# Perform action on all data

Tags: r, fft

I have a lot of csv files with data. I want to perform the same action on all my files, but I do not know how to do this without doing it individually for all the files.

I read in all the csv files and saved the data in my environment with the command:

```
files <- list.files(path=path, pattern="*.csv") 
for(file in files) {  
    perpos <- which(strsplit(file, "")[[1]]==".")   
    assign(gsub(" ","",substr(file, 1, perpos-1)), 
           read.csv(paste(path,file,sep="")))
}
```

The action I am trying to perform is fft(x) (fast fourier transform) on a vector.  For example, if the file name is data1, I would like to do fft(data1$vector).  I would like to do this for all data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way I've found to do this is to use some utility functions from the `data.table` package: `fread` (a faster file reader) and `rbindlist` (consolidate a list into a single data table or data frame).

Something along these lines should do what you want:

```
files <- list.files(path = path, pattern = "*.csv")

# Read your files into a list of data tables 
# (if you want data frames, set data.table = FALSE)
data <- lapply(files, fread)

data <- rbindlist(data, use.names = TRUE, fill = TRUE)
```

You may need additional arguments to `fread` depending on the specifics of your files. And you might not need to specify `use.names` or `fill`.

Comment: `rbindlist()` also has an `idcol` argument from 1.9.5 which automatically generates an id for entries read from each file.